# Prevent the "Update Values:" dialog box from opening every time a cell with a link is modified

Tags: excel, vba

Quick version: I've got broken links in a file I'm working with because they're pointing to someone else's hard drive.  A macro went wrong in someone else's file that converted all formulas to text by appending an apostrophe before the formula.  I wrote a macro to fix this, but there are a ton of external links in the file.  The macro essentially changes a formula from the first line to the second line below, doing nothing more than removing the unnecessary apostrophe.

```
1) '='C:\OtherPersonsFolderPath\[FileName.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1
2)  ='C:\OtherPersonsFolderPath\[FileName.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1
```

If I do this manually, Excel opens a dialog box asking me to "Update Values" in FileName.xlsm by pointing to the right file.  I don't want to update the file path though: I plan to give this back to the original owner of the file with all paths in tact, sans apostrophes.  If I hit the "cancel" button on that dialog box, I get the intended effect: The formula updates to what I need, and the value changes to whatever it used to be back when it was a working link.  It works fine if I manually hit "cancel" on the box every time it pops up, but I've got thousands of cells to iterate through across dozens of sheets.  I need a way to tell VBA to say "cancel" in that box, or prevent the box from appearing in the first place.  Any ideas?  My code is below:

```
Public Sub MyBugFix()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Note that I unsuccessfully tried options like "ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever" and "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" here

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To WS_Count
    Sheets(I).Visible = True
    Sheets(I).Select
    Range("A1:BZ400").Select

    'Simple fix for embedded apostrophes in formulas (e.g., an equals sign in an IF statement)
        Selection.Replace What:="'=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    'More complex fix for apostrophes at the start (they're special characters, so the find/replace trick doesn't work)
        Dim myRng As Range
        Dim myCell As Range
        Set myRng = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set myRng = Intersect(Selection, _
        Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
        On Error Resume Next

        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            If myCell.PrefixCharacter <> "" Then
            myCell.Value = "" & myCell.Text
            On Error Resume Next
            End If
        Next myCell
Next I

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Does adding Application.DisplayAlerts = False at the start and Application.DisplayAlerts = True at the end sort it out?

Comment: What happens if you set `Application.EnableAlerts` to false?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/506273-turn-off-update-values-dialog-box.html so I can't claim any credit for it!

Put this before you edit the formula ...

`ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever`

Then turn it back on after you have made your edits...

`ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways`

This solved a similar problem for me, where I was using VBA to write cell formula containing references to other spreadsheets.  All credit goes to AlphaFrog on the MrExcel forum!

Answer (score 4):

I found out a combination of commands:

```
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

'your macro

```
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Best Regards

Comment: This is the same as Loophole's answer, no?

Answer (score 0):

**Disabling the Select Sheet or Update Values dialog:**

[image: Select Sheet external reference dialog]

This short macro's use of the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) should quickly sweep away any prefixing tick (aka `'`, single-quote or `Chr(39)`) [.PrefixCharacters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) from an entire workbook. While the operation is intended to target formulas that have been commented out of operation with a `'`, it will also revert text that looks like numbers to true numbers.

```
Sub Clean_Prefix_Ticks()
    Dim w As Long, c As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook   '<- set this workbook properly if necessary
        For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            With Worksheets(w).UsedRange
                For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    With .Columns(c)
                        If CBool(Application.CountA(.Cells)) Then _
                            .Cells.TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), _
                                    DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
                    End With
                Next c
            End With
        Next w
    End With
End Sub
```

The bulk nature of removing the [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) allows the Text-to-Columns operation to sweep through each worksheet's [.UsedRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) without raising the external reference **Select Sheet** dialog.

If there was sufficient need, each column could easily be examined before the operation took place. The above code was written to handle a workbook-wide sweep.

> Caveat: The [TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is set to **xlGeneralFormat**. Be advised that you may lose some forms of special cell formatting that you have assigned; especially text formatting on characters within a string (e.g. [Range .Characters property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198232.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Data/edit link/Startup Prompt and then click on
Don't display the alert and don't update automatic links.

[image: Update Value every time i paste]