# ExecuteExcel4Macro & update values dialog box

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I'm currently coding a small VBA tool in order to quickly sort files according to some data inside. As an example, I have a "To be sorted" folder with some files in it, lets say "File1.xls, File2.xls" and so on.

To read data in "FileX.xls", I use `ExecuteExcel4Macro` (with the range and filename set properly), then I can use this data to apply filters and move files in other directories.

My code works fine with local files, but when I try to run it on my server (the tool aims at sorting files stored on the server), a dialog box "Update values" appears when I use `ExecuteExcel4Macro`.

From here, I have to options:

- manually opening each file before running the macro (I have like 250 files to sort so...)
- pressing cancel on the dialog box which causes the plugin to crash (type mismatch error)

Here is the portion of code that bothers me

```
For Each fsoFile In fsoParentFol.Files

    'I only want to sort .xls files
    If Right(fsoFile.Name, 4) = ".xls" Then
        'On active le workbook actuel
        strRef = "'[" & fsoFile.Name & "]" & "Sheet1" & "'!"

        'this is the data I want to retrieve ... and this is where the dialog pops up
        projectName = ExecuteExcel4Macro(strRef & rngProjectName.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1))
        
        'some more code goes here but is irrelevant
    End If
Next fsoFile
```

So my question is: how can I disable this dialog or, if it's a bad idea, are there other clean methods (I don't want to open each workbook, even with screenupdate turned off) that could solve my issue?

`DisplayAlerts = False` doesn't solve the problem. And again, the program runs fine without this dialog.

I've of course tried to research online my problem first before posting here, but even subjects like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722693/prevent-the-update-values-dialog-box-from-opening-every-time-a-cell-with-a-li) aren't solutions to my problem.

Comment: Are you using a UNC path or an actual drive letter?

Comment: Hi ! I'm using an UNC path

Comment: And is the server mapped to your computer as a network drive?

Comment: Actually, it's both ... Server as an UNC address AND a drive letter.

Comment: The update values dialog usually appears when the path you've provided isn't valid. I'd check the value of `strRef` just before you run the `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` method by sticking a breakpoint in there (press F9 when you're on that line)

Comment: Damned you were right ! For some reason, when I run the script from a server location, I have to change the path using the Server drive letter ...

Thx a lot ! (even if I don't understand why it's working well when I run it from the desktop).

Can you post a repply so I can mark your answer as correct ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the UNC path to a path using the drive letter that the server is mapped to:

So for example, change your string to produce:

```
[P:\Some_Folder\myfile.xls]Sheet1!A1
```

Instead of:

```
[\\my-server\Some_Folder\myfile.xls]Sheet1!A1
```

---

You could try using the replace function to achieve this:

```
strRef = "'[" & Replace(fsoFile.Name, "\\", "P:\") & "]" & "Sheet1" & "'!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use code more like this:

```
projectName = Workbooks.Open("\\srv1\folder\Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Close
```

This works with a mapped network drive too.

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I think I'll go with this solution if I can't find any other one ... using executeExcel4Macro seemed cleaner to me though :/