# Running macro through PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to run a macro through a PowerShell script. I figured out how to start the macro.

```
$ExcelPath = "R:\01.DS\04.X-DS\13. Proposed plan\Proposed_plan_WINGS.xlsm"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.Worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$Excel.Run('Iris_prop_plan')
```

However, when the macro starts, a popup appears which says: update values.
How do I include this in the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent the “Update Values:” dialog box from opening every time a cell with a link is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26722693/1630171).

Comment: Hi, this does not work for me.

Comment: _this does not work for me_ is a little vague. There were 3 suggestions in that linked post. You tried all of them and it changed _nothing_ and you still get the problem? If it didnt help I would add what you specifically tried as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: Hi, "displayalerts is false" stops showing the popupbox, but the macro is leaving out key steps linked with adding the values. "xlUpdateLinksNever" is not recognized as a command in powershell.

Comment: [`[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants]::xlUpdateLinksNever`](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2psh.shtml). Aside from that I doubt we can do anything else without knowing the code of your macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# start Excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
#open file
$FilePath = 'FilePath'
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
##If you will like to check what is happend
$excel.Visible = $true
## Here you can "click" the button
$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run("MacroName")

       ##The macro name is the trigger of your button
```