# How do I prevent the Excel "We can't update links" dialogue when formulas pointing to non-existent internal sheets are purposeful?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am making an Excel 2016 database. Part of the design are large Consolidated Data worksheets that reference cells in monthly data sheets. For example, the Consolidated Data sheet may reference:

```
='Datasheet Feb2017'!D3
```

Although many cell references are more complex:

```
=IF(ISREF('Datasheet Jun2017'!A1),IF(XLOOKUP($A4,'Datasheet Jun2017'!D4:N4,'Datasheet Jun2017'!D6:N6,NA()) = "", NA(),   XLOOKUP($A4,'Datasheet Jun2017'!D4:N4,'Datasheet Jun2017'!D6:N6,NA())),NA())
```

These references work as intended. When the datasheet exists, it displays the appropriate data. When the datasheet doesn't exist, it displays #N/A. I do this so that as I add additional months of data, the consolidated data worksheet automatically updates. A limited number of these references to not-yet-created workbooks are constructed through INDIRECT.

The only problem is that upon opening the workbook I will always get this message:

> This workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe.
> If you trust these links, update them to get the latest data. Otherwise, you can keep working with the data you have.

This is strange because there are no external links. All references are internal. When I select Update:

> We can't updates some of the links in your workbook right now. You can continue without updating their values, or edit the links you think are wrong.

I suspect this is referring to the references to not-yet-created worksheets.

This is a macro-enabled workbook.

How can I prevent both of these dialogues on startup?

Comment: Have you tried having a cell set to 1 or 0 to show if the datasheet exists, then wrap your link in an if() so if yhe cell is 1 it gets selected.

Comment: This still has a cell referencing the nonexistant sheet; even if the reference isn't used it still gives errors, from what I can tell.

Comment: Well, I am not going to argue with you, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to an [adjacent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722693/prevent-the-update-values-dialog-box-from-opening-every-time-a-cell-with-a-li) that seems to work, from user zerala:

I put this around my startup macro:

```
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

'your macro

```
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```